# How to write an awk script to list users currently using the system along with a count of the number of times they have logged in?

Tags: linux, unix, awk

I pretty new on Unix and just started exploring awk. I am aware, using "who", we can get the list of users, and "wc" to get the count, but not sure how to write them in a script file and then run that from prompt.I have basic idea of the format, awk -f scriptname.awk filename to run from a file. Please guide me through this.

Comment: [awk guide](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
who | awk '{w[$1]++} END { for (x in w) { print x,"has "w[x]"active sessions" }}'
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance. As I understand, field 1 in every line is stored in array and then it is referred at the END section using for loop. Correct me if my understanding is wrong.

Comment: field 1 is stored in a hash iterator (similar to an array). When you see the same username it will iterate it. The end statement, simply prints the username and its occurrences. Hope this helps